# what does a while loop with semicolon mean

Tags: c, pic

I have a issue with a while loop.

```
while(!PORTB.F4);           //Waiting for Echo
T1CON.F0 = 1;               //Timer Starts
while(PORTB.F4);            //Waiting for Echo goes LOW
T1CON.F0 = 0;               //Timer Stops
```

does this equal to,

```
while(!PORTB.F4){ 
   T1CON.F0 = 1;               
}
while(PORTB.F4){            
   T1CON.F0 = 0;   
}
```

Comment: No of course they are not the same.  Any basic C book would tell you that. And running some simple tests would also tell you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `while(!PORTB.F4);` basically means "Execute `PORTB.F4` until it returns/equals true".

Here's what (I think) your code does, based on the comments:

```
while (!PORTB.F4);          // Wait for PORTB.F4 to equal 1 (true)
T1CON.F0 = 1;               // When PORTB.F4 equals 1, set T1CON.F0 to true
while (PORTB.F4);           // Wait for PORTB.F4 to equal 0 (false)
T1CON.F0 = 0;               // When PORTB.F4 equals 0, set T1CON.F0 to false
```